# Rate order of decomposition of hydrogen peroxide

Tags: catalysis, decomposition

I have been having some troubles finding a source for my investigation. I am inverstigating the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide, which (according to my teacher/supervisor) is a second order reaction with the use of catalase, and looks like this:

$$\ce{Rate = [H2O2][catalase]}$$
My investigation requires the rate order, but I am not supposed to calculate it myself due to "the high chance of errors in the experiment". I thought this wouldn't be an issue and was willing to investigate said rate equation myself, though it is not an option at my school and the teacher. I have been advised to find a source which states proves this, though I have been having hard time doing so myself.

Are there any articles or research papers I could purchase/read which would allow me to justify my statement for the previously mentioned rate order?